# How to see distribution of data if data range is very big

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to see distribution of my data. I want to use histograms with `Matplotlib` but the problem is that my data has very big range, it kinds look like this:

```
my_data = [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,2,4,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,5,6,5,6,7,8,6,5,4,3,2,4,1,4,5,3,1,3,5,7,4,5635,2,4,5,5,2,2,5,1,1,2,3,5,3,3462,6,6,7,5,4,3,4,5,3,2,1,3,7855]
```

Only problem is that i have more than 5000 elements that are in range 0-6, and a couple of elements that are bigger than 1000.

How can I see distribution of my data so that I can now if I can remove some data from it. If I plot histogram, i can only see one or two bars that shows data from 0-6 but i cant see bars that are showing data that are bigger than 1000 because there is not a lot of them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(my_data, bins = 15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Make the counts axis a log-scale?

Comment: can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: If list contains 0.

```
my_data =[0,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,2,4,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,5,6,5,6,7,8,6,5,4,3,2,4,1,4,5,3,1,3,5,7,4,5635,2,4,5,5,2,2,5,1,1,2,3,5,3,3462,6,6,7,5,4,3,4,5,3,2,1,3,7855]

import numpy as np

my_data = np.array(my_data)
my_data = mydata + 1
my_data = np.log(my_data)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(my_data, bins = 15)
plt.show()
```