# Plot two Histograms with Matplotlib and Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have two lists of numbers:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,4,5,6,8,9,12,3,3,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9,5,3,2,4,5,2,3,4,11,13,4,5,3,5,6,7,11,13,3,4,5,4,5]
list_2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,12,15,16,11,12,7,8,9,7,8,9,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,9,8,9,11,10,12,16,7,8,9,10,10,8,9,8,9,10,10,10,15,16,19]
```

I want to plot two histograms with Python and Matplotlib so that i get result like this:

[image]

I need the line histogram, and I do not know how to plot it. I know how to make bar histogram, but I want to have line histogram so that I can see intersection of this two histograms.

```
plt.hist(list_1, bins = 10)
plt.hist(list_2, bins = 10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) Library can help you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


# Your Data
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,4,5,6,8,9,12,3,3,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9,5,3,2,4,5,2,3,4,11,13,4,5,3,5,6,7,11,13,3,4,5,4,5]
list_2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,12,15,16,11,12,7,8,9,7,8,9,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,9,8,9,11,10,12,16,7,8,9,10,10,8,9,8,9,10,10,10,15,16,19]

# Creating a displot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

sns.distplot(list_1, kde=True, ax = ax, hist=False, bins = 10)
sns.distplot(list_2, kde=True, ax = ax, hist=False, bins = 10)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: try adding this at the end of your code: plt.show();

Comment: Thank you my friend, can you help me with this also?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703740/how-to-see-distribution-of-data-if-data-range-is-very-big

Comment: Can you elaborate your question in your other post? From what I understand, you wanna know the number of instances that a specific value appeared

Comment: Can you just tell me what does Y axis represent?
X axis are the values that I have in my lists, but whats x axis?